# Ansible code not working

Tags: ansible

Im trying to use  ansible to ping  google.com fas a test for internet access on my node. The code works well when the ping replies come back but for failed attempts I get a dict object error. Can someone please sanity check the below code for me? Also listed below is the error that I'm getting. Im sure it's just a minor issue.

```
  - name: Checking Internet Access
ios_command:
  commands: ping www.google.com source g0/1.1
  provider: "{{cli}}"
  wait_for:
  - result[0] contains "!!!"
register: result

failed_when: "not '!!!' in result.stdout[0]"
```

> fatal: [192.168.12.252]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check 'not '!!!' in result.stdout[0]' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (not '!!!' in result.stdout[0]): 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'"}

Comment: Looks like a syntax problem.  Switch `result.stdout[0]` to `result[0].stdout`.

Comment: Tried that and I'm getting the error  'dict object has no element 0'

Comment: Maybe just `result.stdout`?  Try adding a debug task after to print out the contents of `result`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use the command's exit code (return code) in result.rc, instead of reading and matching text output. From the man page on Debian 9:

> If  ping does not receive any reply packets at all it will exit with code 1. If a packet count and deadline are both specified, and fewer than count
>          packets are received by the time the deadline has arrived, it will also exit with code 1.  On other error it exits with code 2. Otherwise  it  exits
>          with code 0.

For example:

```
- hosts: short.fritz.box
  tasks:
  - name: checking ping response from magnus
    command: ping -c 3 magnus.fritz.box
    register: result
    failed_when: result.rc != 0
```

Tested with Ansible 2.3.1 on Debian 9.1. It succeeds when magnus is running and reachable, fails when magnus is paused.